# In Rspec how does one download content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, rspec

I want to download from a website during my rspec test

I do not want to stub the API usage for this specific function. 
I don't plan on doing a heap of test against an API.  For that I hope shall trust the stubbing. 
But I think it's a good idea to do at least one test against an API.

Here is some sample code that replicates the issue I'm having:

```
require 'vcr'
context 'test vcr off' do
  it 'should work' do
    VCR.turn_off!
    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI('http://www.google.com.au/?q=tester'))
    print res.body
  end
end
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Failure/Error: res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI('http://www.google.com.au/?q=tester'))
     WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
       Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET http://www.google.com.au/?q=tester with headers 
       {'Accept'=>'*/*', 
        'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3',
        'Host'=>'www.google.com.au', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}

       You can stub this request with the following snippet:

       stub_request(:get, "http://www.google.com.au/?q=tester").
         with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Host'=>'www.google.com.au', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
         to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

The Doc's I've read on VCR indicate that the above code should work.

Comment: Can you share your VCR configuration from your spec_helper.rb? And what VCR version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I really hate when this happens.. 
I search and search for an answer and then I post a question. 
Then minutes later I find the answer..

```
1 require 'vcr'
2 context 'test vcr off' do
3   it 'should work' do
4     VCR.turn_off!
5     WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow => "www.google.com.au")
6     res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI('http://www.google.com.au/?q=tester'))
7     print res.body
8   end
9 end
```

The answer was on line 5.. this let me make the call.. I mean I get a pile of junk on the screen, but it doesn't fail... no exception.